# Convergence condition for an integral

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find the convergence condition on variable p for the following definite integral to be convergent but I am unable to:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x^p+x^{-p})log(1+x)}{x}dx$$

I am currently just trying to just integrate the problem and then find the condition on p but am getting nowhere, is there some other way to find convergent condition?

Comment: Consider using the comparison test. The $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$ factor is bounded on the unit interval.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll assume that $p>0$ for simplicity. The only problematic term is the one with a factor of $x^{-p}$, which might cause convergence issues near the origin. Thus, we must also have $p<1$.